# Ocassionally-unreliable DATE field of http response

Tags: http, time

We're interested in the rough timezone of the user, give or take a few hours, and for *reasons* we don't trust the user's device clock.

One cheap and easy thing we tried is to post a GET (a HEAD would work too) to (eg) google.com, and look for the DATE field of the header. This is, by the http standard, always in GMT. This may fall foul of caching, so we added a ?rng=XXXXXX to the end.

However in some cases the date field seems to be way off. Like, days off. The previous and next request get the correct date. Now maybe I just need to add more digits to my cache-beating rng field, but could something else be going on? Are there any flaws or downsides in this plan, considering we don't care about second-accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

We seem pretty sure that given our player install base, and the frequency of these checks, and the poorness of our random suffix, that google/someone in between was able to cache them successfully.

Seems like a good rule not to use http headers for authoritative time, unless you control the server and can send non-caching responses.